# How to use a JSON object value as a Foreign Key in another JSON object?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

In my Angular app, I am using HTTPClient to read some JSON files.

My files are `offers.json` & `managers.json`.

Here are the interfaces used to read both JSON files:

```
export interface IOffer {
    id: number;
    managerId: number;
}

export interface IManager {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
}
```

The below table displays the data in `offers.json`.

```
<table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="offers && offers.length">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Offer ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Manager ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let offer of offers">
        <td>{{offer.id}}</td>
        <td>{{offer.managerId}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of displaying the `managerId` value, I want to use it to search `managers.json` so I can display the `fullName` value.

Can someone please tell me how I can use the `managerId` from `offers.json` to populate the above table with `fullName` from `managers.json`?

I am looking for something like this:

[image: here]

Where the *Offer ID* above is from `offers.json` & the `managerId` is used to search `managers.json` & display the *fullName*

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to achieve this is with a View Model. You can think of a view model as an interface that describes the data to be displayed on your page.

Create a new interface with properties for the offer id and manager name, like so:

```
interface OfferAndManagerVM {
  offerId: number;
  managerName: string;
}
```

Now, use the power of observables to map your offer and manager data into the view model - something like this:

```
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const offersAndManagers: Observable<OfferAndManagerVM[]> = combineLatest(
  offerService.getOffers(),
  managerService.getManagers(),
).pipe(
  map((data: [IOffer[], IManager[]]) =>
    data[0].map(offer => {
      const manager = data[1].find(manager => manager.id === offer.managerId);
      const managerName = manager != null ? manager.fullName : null;
      return {
        offerId: offer.id,
        managerName,
      };
    }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hmm, this is probably a better solution than mine. I need to work on rxjs.

Comment: Yours would work too and is less code. But it's a little less efficient because each time angular runs it's change detection mechanism, the getName function is called for each offer record

Comment: @MaxMumford Thanks for your answer. Is this scalable? I only mentioned _offerId_ and _managerName_ to explain my question easily. The actual implementation will look to display _jobName_ and _employeeName_ alongisde _offerId_ and _managerName_. These are all from seperate JSON files. Is the best approach to use your ViewModel above to include all of these pieces?

Comment: Yes I'd say so - you can combine as many different data streams as you want, and it's pretty efficient clientside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of the below:

1. Manually search the managers.json using a lookup, something like `managers.find(e => e.id==searchID).name`.
2. Restructure your query that fetches the json data to include the value you want to display, such that your manager name is included with the offers.json.

There is no default concept of foreign keys in objects. You either include an id to perform a lookup in another array, or you include the relevant information.

If you want to modify your existing table, you just need to write a function to take in the manager id, find the name, and return the name.

```js
getName(id) {
  return this.managers.find(e => e.id == id).name;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="offers && offers.length">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Offer ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Manager ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let offer of offers">
      <td>{{offer.id}}</td>
      <td>{{getName(manager.id)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```